# nonexhaustive binding failure in sml code

Tags: smlnj

I'm supposed to right a function less(e, L) int * int list -> int list that returns a list of all the elements in L that are smaller then e. I wrote this:

```
    fun less(_, nil) = nil
      | less(e, L) =
        let
           val x::xs = less (e, tl L)
        in
           if e > hd L then hd L::x::xs
           else nil @ x::xs
        end;
```

I'm getting a binding failure, surely in the let in bit. I tried a lot of different thinfs already, and I can't figure out why this is wrong. Can anyone shed a light?

Answer (score 1):

```
val x::xs = less (e, tl L)
```

This does not match the case where the result of `less (e, t1 L)` is the empty list.

A correct implementation of the function is this:

```
fun less (_, nil) = nil
  | less (y, x::xs) =
    let
       val xs' = less (y, xs)
    in
      if x < y then x::xs' else xs'
```

Comment: thanks so much for helping. If I may ask, whats lt(y, xs)?

Comment: typo, should be a recursive call to `less`